# selectOneChoice populate with pre-selected default value

Tags: oracle-adf

I need af:selectOneChoice populated with values from the backing bean and one the value from the list (say index=5) should be selected by default. We are using Oracle Adf 10.*

Can somebody help me  on this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For populating the list values, you can use:

```
<af:selectOneChoice value="val3" label="XXXX" id="soc1" >
      <f:selectItems value="#{YourBean.values}" id="si1"/>
</af:selectOneChoice>
```

In YourBean.java , you will have a method like:

```
public List<SelectItem> getValues() {
   if (list == null) {
            list = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
            list(new SelectItem("val1","Label 1"));
            list(new SelectItem("val2","Label 2"));
            list(new SelectItem("val3","Label 3"));

   }
   return list;
```

}

This way you will see "Label 3" as default value in your choice list.

Comment: Florin, Thanks for comments

Comment: Its strange happening when I moved value="#{backBean.dynamicValue}". In the above scenario, the screen has populated with selected value as a label rather than a drop down. But if apply string (value="blah") then it populated and selected perfectly. Any thoughts ?

Comment: Do you have getDynamicValue() method in your backing bean? Is needed when reading "#{backBean.dynamicValue}" EL

Comment: Yes, I had.                                                                                         <afh:cellFormat>                                                                                      <af:selectOneChoice value="#{backBean.dynamicValue}" label="XXXX" id="soc1" >
<f:selectItems value="#{backBean.values}"/>
</af:selectOneChoice>                                                                             </afh:cellFormat>

Comment: Try to see what you get when using #{'blah'} as value.  Also, log the value returned by getDynamicValue()  to the console.

Comment: Marcus, Its working when I changed backed bean return CoreInputText rather than a string.

Comment: Good job, Pradeep. Magic of ADF10. Please do not forget to mark a response as useful, in case you find it so.

Answer (score 0):

For setting default value, you can use this:

```
<af:selectOneChoice label="My Field"
                    id="MyField" value="#{bindings.MyAttribute.inputValue}"
                    autoSubmit="true"
                    binding="#{MyBean.myField}">
  <f:selectItems value="#{bindings.MyAttribute.items}"
                 id="MyFieldItems"/>
</af:selectOneChoice>
```

Notice that SelectOneChoice field has a binding to a java bean. We will use setter method to set default value.

```
public void setMyField(RichSelectOneChoice myField) {
    // since getter/setter methods are called multiple times on
    // page load, we need to prevent setting attribute value more than once
    if(myField != null && myField.getValue() == null){
        ADFUtils.setBoundAttributeValue("MyAttribute", "SomeValue");
    }
    this.myField = myField;
}
```

For setting default index (for example, first from the list) we can use a similar approach:

```
public void setMyField(RichSelectOneChoice myField) {
    if(myField != null && myField.getValue() == null){
        // default value will be 1st from the list
        myField.setValue(0);
    }
    this.myField = myField;
}
```